# Creating Virtual Environment in Windows

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment using `conda create -n venv` inside the project folder and activated the `venv` environment. However, I face the following issues:

1. The `venv` environment is getting created under `C:\Users\Rajesh\anaconda3\envs` folder.
2. When I install packages while in the `venv` environment, the packages not getting installed in `venv` folder. Please advise what is going wrong here

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. When your prompt says (venv), can you tell me what it says when you type `pip list` ?

Comment: when I run pip list command, it lists all the packages and version number.

Comment: That's good. I think your virtual environment is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

1. The default path of virtual env is located `$USER/anaconda3/env`, no matter where you execute the create command, the env created will be put in this path. You could change this default path by editing `$HOME/.condarc`:

```yaml
envs_dirs:
  - some path you like
pkgs_dirs:
  - some path you like
```

2. Are you sure you have executed `conda activate venv` before installing packages?

Comment: Yes I executed the conda activate venv . I installed the packages at (venv) C:\Users\Rajesh\flasky> prompt.

Comment: That's right, `the packages not getting installed in venv folder` means you could not find the package under `$USER/anaconda2/venv` or you were not able to import this module in python? If you can import this module then I'm sure it has been installed correctly. Also you and use `conda list (pip list)` to check whether it is in the pkg list if you use `conda install package-name` (if you use `pip package-name`).